# Programmatically created views in Android do not inherit the theme specified in the manifest file

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I have a project with the theme defined in the manifest file. When I use XML to define the views, the theme is inherited and applied, however when I create the views programmatically, no theme is applied. How do I get the theme defined in the manifest file to also apply to activities with programmatic created views?

Here is a code sample. How do I get the manifest theme to propagate to the Button created in the sample?

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button button = new Button(this);
layout.addView(button, params);
setContentView(layout);
```

Here is the definition from the manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomTheme"
```

Here is the definition of the CustomTheme in the styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

I have tried the following options using the view's constructor:

```
new LinearLayout(context, null, R.style.Theme_MobileSheriff);
new LinearLayout(context, null, 0, R.style.Theme_MobileSheriff);
new LinearLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_MobileSheriff), null, 0, R.style.Theme_MobileSheriff);
```

I have found several articles on stack overflow asking the same question, but none of them have the answer and all of them have been asked 5+ years ago.

Please assist.

Comment: I think you need to use the four-parameter `LinearLayout` constructor and pass your theme ID as the fourth parameter. See [the corresponding `View` constructor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html?hl=en#view_4) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have already tried the various constructors of LinearLayout. My theme is still not applied. I have also revised my question to include the options I have tired.